# Error while decrypting a bytes array using AES256 C#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I was doing a program for encrypting private files on another computer apart, where this same formula worked correctly, I don't understand why this part of code doesn't work, even though it worked before:

```
public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 3 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 256;
            AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }

            decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

[image: Error Sample]

I've been trying to find out for about 2 hours because it gives me that error when decrypting, but counting on the little encryption knowledge that I have have it's absolutely impossible.

Comment: Have you checked the data you're passing is encrypted properly?

Comment: Yes, the data is fully encrypted.@MacroMarc

Comment: Finally... The whole problem comes from the chunk size ... im fucking silly. Thank you @MacroMarc for trying to help, cya.

Comment: @KAoTI It happens to everyone :D Please avoid answering your question in comments, instead, post it as an answer. [Yes, answering your own question is okay!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I think you mean "block size". Chunking is usually about splitting the message itself before processing it, which is not what *you* are doing. AES does **never** have a block size of 256 bits, i.e. above is not AES at all - it's the part of Rijndael that is **not** used as AES.

Comment: Think of your message as a chocolate bar. Although it is supposed to be processed block by block, it only breaks into chunks :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when i say ChunkSize i mean ChunkSize, because first of all I split the file into 5Mb bytes array, then i encrypt or decrypt the Byte Array and write the data into the file. 
Problem was, that ChunkSize was like less than 1Mb and thats why CryptographicException arises.

```
                if (File.Exists(FileToDecrypt)) {
                    byte[] PasswordBytes;
                    if (IsFileTypePassword) {
                        PasswordBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),"K3ys\\" + PasswordToDecrypt));
                    } else {
                        PasswordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PasswordToDecrypt);
                    }
                    DecryptFile(5000000, FileToDecrypt, PasswordBytes); // Here was the problem
                    DecThread.Abort();
                }
```

And here is the function that splits the file, its a little bit different than mine but it does the same, also this piece of code is grabbed from another Question form StackOverflow.

```
public static void SplitFile(string inputFile, int chunkSize, string path)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];

    using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (input.Position < input.Length)
        {
            using (Stream output = File.Create(path + "\\" + index))
            {
                int chunkBytesRead = 0;
                while (chunkBytesRead < chunkSize)
                {
                    int bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 
                                               chunkBytesRead, 
                                               chunkSize - chunkBytesRead);

                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    chunkBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }
                output.Write(buffer, 0, chunkBytesRead);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```